# Mustache is throwing an error about the null value

Tags: kotlin, nullable, mustache

I have a following Kotlin object type with default null value for a field:

```
data class Field(
   val content: String? = null,
   val field: String = ""
)
```

Then I try to pass the object:

```
val myObject = Field(field = "something")
```

to the mustache template:

```
<!DOCTYPE ...>
<html>
<head>
    <meta .../>
</head>
<body ...">

{{#myObject}}
   {{#content}}
       {{.}}<br/>
   {{/content}}
   {{#field}}
       {{.}}<br/>
   {{/field}}
{{/myObject}}

</body>
</html>
```

And after filling the template I receive an exception: `No key, method or field with name 'content' on line ...`
I cannot get what can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

may be you should define the "" for the content default for the problem?

Comment: yes, it is possible. but i this case it will generate an empty line in the doc.

Comment: @youngDev yes,i don't familiar with the 'mustache template',but has any method to compare it with null ,use js  or like this https://retentionscience.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003025814-How-To-Build-HTML-for-Conditional-Statements

Comment: this question is posted for the people who ARE familiar with kotlin, mustache and the potential reason of the problem